# Consultas en paralelo, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo una duda enorme con respecto al framework Laravel (5.6) que se relaciona con el modo de funcionamiento de sus controladores. Para explicarme de mejor forma, dejare un ejemplo que acabo de poner a prueba.

He creado un controlador llamado "MultiController" y he creado dos funciones en el:

```
public function first()
{
    sleep(10);
    echo(Carbon::now());
}

public function second()
{
    sleep(5);
    echo(Carbon::now());
}
```

Ademas, he creado dos rutas en el archivo "web.php" con el fin de ejecutar, en cada una de ellas, las funciones:

```
Route::get('/first', 'MultiController@first');

Route::get('/second', 'MultiController@second');
```

Finalmente, serví mi proyecto con el comando:

```
php artisan serve --host=MI_IP --port=8000
```

Ahora bien, yo entiendo que si desde una IP "A" ingreso a miip:8000/first
 y desde una IP "B" ingreso a miip:8000/second ninguno de ellos tendría que esperar a que el proceso de una función culmine para que la suya se ejecute, pero es justo lo que ocurre.

Si yo ingreso a /first y un instante después, otra persona (desde una IP ajena a la mía) ingresa a /second entonces ella debe esperar 15 segundos (los 10 segundos que tarda mi operación y los 5 segundos que tarda la suya) para ver la fecha que estoy imprimiendo en pantalla con el echo, cosa que no tiene sentido alguno.

Existe alguna forma de que un proceso no afecte al otro de esta forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se "soluciona" al utilizar un servidor web "real". Servidor web que utilizas está pensado para desarrollo, no para producción como está aclarado en la documentación de [PHP: Servidor Web Interno](http://php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php)

> ADVERTENCIA: Este servidor web ha sido diseñado para ayudar al desarrollo de aplicaciones. También puede ser útil para propósitos de prueba o para demostraciones de aplicaciones que se ejecutan en entornos controlados. No se pretende que sea un servidor web con todas las funciones. No debe ser utilizado en una red pública.

Saludos

Comment: Te refieres a que estoy sirviendo mi proyecto en localhost? Porque no lo sirvo ahí. Por cierto, esa url esta rota...

Comment: Cuando ejecutas `php artisan serve` lo que haces es utilizar el servidor web interno de php. Este es monohilo, por eso tiene que terminar con la primer petición antes de poder atender la segunda. (Ya corregí el link)

Comment: Vale, vale. Realice un deploy en Heroku y todo corre como deberia. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!